# Is it safe to remove snapd from ubuntu server?

Tags: server, snap

I have a 18.04.3 server set up running an OpenVPN server. This machine has fairly limited RAM since it is running on a virtual host with other servers. *This machine is soley dedicated to VPN* and is an important service for my work.

I noticed lots of snapd processes taking up much of the RAM. Is it safe to uninstall (or event just stop the processes) snapd to gain back this precious resource?

Comment: `snapd` is useful if and only if you want to install some app from snap: https://snapcraft.io/store In your case, I think you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**If you are not using snaps**, then it is safe to uninstall snapd. Several OpenVPN implementations are in the Snap Store, so do be sure you are not using one of them.

```
snap list                    // List the snaps installed on your system
sudo apt remove snapd        // Uninstall snapd
```

If you change your mind and wish to begin using snaps, then you must reinstall snapd.

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

A future release-upgrade may re-install snapd, and you might need to remove it again.